# Can I remove the last 3 widget host of the tablet I have?

Tags: tablet, app-widgets

This is maybe silly question but I don't know how to get it.

When I start my android Tablet then I see 5 widget host where I can drag my app for easily run. I have removed few apps and now end 3 are blanks.

Now I want to remove them how I can do it. My android id 4.0.3.

Any guess.

Comment: "Widget host"? Do you mean "home screen"? Removing unneeded home screens is largely a function of the launcher you're using. As far as I know that's not a function of the default Android launcher.

Comment: Please update the question to say what tablet you have. Different manufacturers have different home screens on their tablets.

Answer (score 0):

To remove any icon from the home screen, be it a widget or an app shortcut:-

- Tap and hold to pick it up
- A bin/trashcan icon will appear
- Drag the icon onto the bin
- Drop it

Comment: I want to remove the spacer (what you call in programming language) where I have host my icon to fastly use.